# obj-c : iphone programming NSTimeInterval problem

Tags: objective-c, time, intervals

i got a problem with my time interval. I need to get the interval of two times in this format : HH:MM. If i enter : 15:35 and 16:35 it is ok, but when i do 20:30 to 01:30, it gives me like 18 hours interval.. anyone have an idea?

```
        NSString *startDate= starthere.text;
    NSString *endDate = endhere.text;


    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

    NSDate *dateSelected = [dateFormatter dateFromString:startDate];        
    NSDate *dateSelected2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:endDate];
    [dateFormatter release];





        if ([dateSelected2 earlierDate:dateSelected] == dateSelected2)
        {
            dateSelected2 = [dateSelected2 dateByAddingTimeInterval:86400];
        }





interval = [dateSelected2 timeIntervalSinceDate:dateSelected];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your end date is *before* your start date, so there *are* 19 hours between them.  A quick fix might be to add 24 hours to your end date if it compares as earlier than the start date.  Something like:

```
if ([dateSelected2 earlierDate:dateSelected] == dateSelected2)
{
    dateSelected2 = [dateSelected2 dateByAddingTimeInterval:86400];
}
```

The [NSDate documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/dateByAddingTimeInterval:) has everything you need to know.

Comment: @th1nz4ne, it works for me here.  Are you on an older version of OS X?  If you're using something older than 10.6, you need `addTimeInterval:` instead of `dateByAddingTimeInterval:`.

Comment: i used add time interval and it works... its wierd i have 10.6